# What does 'myVariable.(type)' return exactly?

Tags: pointers, go, switch-statement

I created a simple code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 5
    b := &a

    Test(b)

    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(*b)
}

func Test(result interface{}){

    switch r := result.(type) {
        case *int:
            *r = 10
    }
}
```

You can run it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/fFoeMl2gDj)

In Test method inside switch statement I create new variable that is a type of my parameter. 
Why does my variable 'b' update after update of this pointer. Why does this new variable points to the old one?

The result of program execution is

```
10
10
```

But expected

```
5
5
```

**UPDATE**

I'd like to precise the question. I did not assign my pointer to 'b' to variable 'r' in Test.
I expect that

```
 r := result.(type)
```

gives me the type of the result. But why if I change value of a pointer of a new variable result is changed too

**UPDATE 2**

As suggested I checked again a specification and didn't found an answer. In the next construction

```
switch r := result.(type) {
    case *int:
        *r = 10
}
```

What does `result.(type)` return exactly?

> A type switch compares types rather than values. It is otherwise similar > to an expression switch. It is marked by a special switch expression that > has the form of a type assertion using the reserved word type rather than > an actual type:
>
> switch x.(type) {
>   // cases
>   }

Comment: `r` points to `a`, because you passed a pointer to `a`. Can you explain why you would expect the pointer to somehow change value when you passed it to the Test function?

Comment: Jim covered the questions in the body. To answer the question in the title, type assertions return the input value as the given type, as outlined in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Comment: You didn't assign a pointer to `b` to `r`, you assigned a pointer to `a` to `r`. See also the "Type switches" specification under https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements

Comment: "I expect that `r := result.(type)` gives me the type of the result." Don't expect things which are not true. The language works according to the spec and not to your expectations. The spec has nice examples on type switches https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches.

Answer (score 0):

See information on type assertions [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15).

There is a good description of pointers in go [here](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/8).

In your code &a means the address of a and b returns a pointer to an int (*int).

In the Test function you are saying store the value 10 in the memory location pointed to by r.